# How to test a process that involves an email using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, email, verify

For instance login thru email verification requires you receive and respond to an email.

There seems to be a solution in Java called GreenMail.

Does anyone know of a Ruby solution?

Comment: Could you give a bit more insight into the issue? Why cant just a local mail server be a solution, since you can communicate with it using pop3/smtp protocols (from Ruby code as well).

Answer (score 1):

Some options::

- https://mailcatcher.me/ display messages in web interface
- https://github.com/meatballhat/fakesmtpd http API, e.g. GET
- https://github.com/bluerail/post_office SMTP/POP
- https://github.com/koseki/mocksmtpd/ Older

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [gmail](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail) gem to read received emails and do what I need whit them.